# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have fired below Select Statement and I got this error. Any one help me.

```
select top 100 
    MenuID, MenuGroup, MenuName, ObjectName, ObjectTitle 
from tblMenuMaster  
where 
    ApplicationID = 3 
    and recStatus = 'A'
```

Error Message.

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout
>   period has expired.)

Already apply Non Clustered Index on `tblMenuMaster  (MenuGroup,MenuName,ObjectName,ObjectTitle)`.

Answer (score 1):

Its one of the random error which comes on SQL Server. If you reboot your machine and then try to execute the query, mostly it will not come.

You can check this [MSDN blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/) to get the details however.

> Removing Connections
>
> The connection pooler removes a connection from the pool after it has
>   been idle for a long time, or if the pooler detects that the
>   connection with the server has been severed.
>
> Note that a severed connection can be detected only after attempting
>   to communicate with the server. If a connection is found that is no
>   longer connected to the server, it is marked as invalid.
>
> Invalid connections are removed from the connection pool only when
>   they are closed or reclaimed.
>
> If a connection exists to a server that has disappeared, this
>   connection can be drawn from the pool even if the connection pooler
>   has not detected the severed connection and marked it as invalid.
>
> This is the case because the overhead of checking that the connection
>   is still valid would eliminate the benefits of having a pooler by
>   causing another round trip to the server to occur.
>
> When this occurs, the first attempt to use the connection will detect
>   that the connection has been severed, and an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sever connection must be terminated due to which the error occurs. You need to reconnect the server and again fire the query. 
However if this occurs on a frequent basis you need to get in touch with your DBA.